# How can I disable the form confirmation message?

Tags: 7, webforms

I'm referring to the green box that informs the user that they have successfully submitted their form.
In particular, I'm wondering if I can remove it without writing any php. Is there anything in the admin interface?

Comment: Is there a way in your form to show a "success" page?

Comment: After submission, the page is redirected to a "success page" where we have written a "thank you for submitting" message. So, the green confirmation box is redundant.

Comment: Can you / Do you want to edit the theme?

Comment: I can't personally -- that would have to go through a vendor. But at that point I would probably just use php, right?

Comment: Why redirect to a success page if webform has an option to just reload the current page with the thank you message?

Comment: create a template(page.tpl.php) file of your page where your form rendered,then comment the line  <?php print $messages; ?></div> in your template file

Answer (score 0):

There is no option in Drupal's core that gives you the ability to disable messages but there is a module for that: [disable_messages](https://www.drupal.org/project/disable_messages).

Still, I like this approach, which uses [drupal_get_messages](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_get_messages/7.x) function implemented in [hook_form_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7.x):

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */
function my_module_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  // Define the $form_id for the form which you want to suppress messages for.
  if ($form_id == 'hide_messages_form_id') {
    $form['actions']['submit']['#submit'][] = 'my_module_submit';
  }
}

/**
 * My custom submit handler.
 */
function my_module_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  // Hide drupal 'status' messages. Equally use 'error', 'warning' or 'NULL'.
  drupal_get_messages('status');
  // Or display your own message.
  // drupal_set_message(t('My message.'));
}
```